# laravel get score position from relationship table

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables (users and achievements) each user has total score which is calculated based on achievements table data `So far everything works fine`

> Now I need to get user placement between all users based on existing
> score. So I can say user with Id = 5 is in 5th place for example.

`Code`

In achievement model I have as following

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function getAttributeSum() {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach(func_get_args() as $attribute){
        $sum += $this->getAttribute($attribute);
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

And in users model I have this

```
public function achievement()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Achievement::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Then I get my users with their scores like this:

```
$achievement = Achievement::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
$score = $achievement->getAttributeSum('donations', 'shares', 'listens', 'watches', 'readings', 'prayers');
```

Here is how my achievement table looks like:

[image: achievements]

Now I need to get user placement

```
$achievement = Achievement::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
$score = $achievement->getAttributeSum('donations', 'shares', 'listens', 'watches', 'readings', 'prayers');
$placement = ??? // <---- (e.g. 5 of 2000)
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: I think you can do this in a single query in case there is only one row for each user in achievements table . Raw query example `SELECT u.id as userID, (a.donations + a.shares + a.listens + a.watches + a.readings + a.prayers) as placement FROM users as u LEFT JOIN achievements as a  ON u.id = a.user_id ORDER BY placement;`. You can easily transform it into query builder one if you want. In your case you need to grab all users and eager load their achievement's and then sort them by specific field from relation in 
 php in order to have a collection of sorted users that you can display later.